# How to improve performance of single-page application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, backbone.js, rabl

**Introduction**
I have a (mostly) single-page [application](http://domiy.com) built with BackboneJS and a Rails backend.

Because most of the interaction happens on one page of the webapp, when the user first visits the page I basically have to pull a ton of information out of the database in one large deeply joined query.

This is causing me some rather extreme load times on this one page.

[image: load times]

NewRelic appears to be telling me that most of my problems are because of 457 individual fast method calls.

[image: fast methid calls]

Now I've done all the eager loading I can do (I checked with the [Bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet)) and I still have a problem.

These method calls are most likely ocurring in my [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) serializer which I use to serialize a bunch of JSON to embed into the page for initializing Backbone. You don't need to understand all this but suffice to say it could add up to 457 method calls.

```
object @search
attributes :id, :name, :subscription_limit

# NOTE: Include a list of the members of this search.
child :searchers => :searchers do
  attributes :id, :name, :gravatar_icon
end

# Each search has many concepts (there could be over 100 of them).
child :concepts do |search|
  attributes :id, :title, :search_id, :created_at

  # The person who suggested each concept.
  child :suggester => :suggester do
    attributes :id, :name, :gravatar_icon
  end

  # Each concept has many suggestions (approx. 4 each).
  node :suggestions do |concept|
    # Here I'm scoping suggestions to only ones which meet certain conditions.
    partial "suggestions/show", object: concept.active_suggestions
  end

  # Add a boolean flag to tell if the concept is a favourite or not.
  node :favourite_id do |concept|
    # Another method call which occurs for each concept.
    concept.favourite_id_for(current_user)
  end
end

# Each search has subscriptions to certain services (approx. 4). 
child :service_subscriptions do
  # This contains a few attributes and 2 fairly innocuous method calls.
  extends "service_subscriptions/show"
end
```

So it seems that I need to do something about this but I'm not sure what approach to take. Here is a list of potential ideas I have:

**Performance Improvement Ideas**

Dumb-Down the Interface
Maybe I can come up with ways to present information to the user which don't require the actual data to be present. I don't see why I should absolutely need to do this though, other single-page apps such as [Trello](http://trello.com) have incredibly complicated interfaces.

Concept Pagination
If I paginate concepts it will reduct the amount of data being extracted from the database each time. Would product an inferior user interface though.

Caching
At the moment, refreshing the page just extracts the entire search out of the DB again. Perhaps I can cache parts of the app to reduce on DB hits. This seems messy though because not much of the data I'm dealing with is static.

Multiple Requests
It is technically bad to serve the page without embedding the JSON into the page but perhaps the user will feel like things are happening faster if I load the page unpopulated and then fetch the data.

Indexes
I should make sure that I have indexes on all my foreign keys. I should also try to think about places where it would help to have indexes (such as favourites?) and add them.

Move Method Calls into DB
Perhaps I can cache some of the results of the iteration I do in my view layer into the DB and just pull them out instead of computing them. Or I could sync things on write rather than on read.

**Question**
Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should be spending my time on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer without being able to see the actual user interface, but I would focus on loading exactly only as much data as is required to display the initial interface. For example, if the user has to drill down to see some of the data you're presenting, then you can load that data on demand, rather than loading it as part of the initial payload. You mention that a search can have as many as 100 "concepts," maybe you don't need to fetch all of those concepts initially?

Bottom line, it doesn't sound like your issue is really on the client side -- it sounds like your server-side code is slowing things down, so I'd explore what you can do to fetch less data, or to defer the complex queries until they are definitely required.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend separating your JS code-base into modules that are dynamically loaded using an asset loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). This way you won't have so many XHRs firing at load time.

When a specific module is needed it can load and initialize at an appropriate time instead of every page load.

If you complicate your code a little, each module should be able to start and stop. So, if you have any `polling` occurring or complex code executing you can stop the module to increase performance and decrease the network load.

Comment: While I agree that optimising asset delivery is an important step in increasing performance, I don't think it is the main issue I'm having here. While there is a lit of JS in the app, it is gzipped, minified and arrives in at ~100kb. It should also be cached on the client side so the cost of loading is minimized for repeat visitors.